# Prove that for every $k\geq 1$, $1\cdot 3\cdot(1!)^2+....+k\cdot(k+2)\cdot(k!)^2=((k+1)!)^2-1$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that for every $k\ge1,$

$\displaystyle1\cdot3\cdot(1!)^2+2\cdot4\cdot(2!)^2+....+k\cdot(k+2)\cdot(k!)^2=((k+1)!)^2-1$

I start off with considering induction, but I can't quite get the left side to match the right side. Maybe there is something I'm not seeing or a calculation I have wrong. Any kind of help would be great!

$\displaystyle((n+1)!)^2-1+(n+1)(n+3)((n+1)!)^2=((n+2)!)^2-1$

LHS:

$\displaystyle((n+1)!)^2[(n+1)(n+3)-1]$

$\displaystyle((n+1)!)^2[(n+2)^2-2]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$\displaystyle f(k): 1\cdot3\cdot(1!)^2+2\cdot4\cdot(2!)^2+....+k\cdot(k+2)\cdot(k!)^2=((k+1)!)^2-1$  holds true for $k=m$

$\displaystyle\implies 1\cdot3\cdot(1!)^2+2\cdot4\cdot(2!)^2+....+m\cdot(m+2)\cdot(m!)^2=\{(m+1)!\}^2-1 $

For $k=m+1,$

$\displaystyle\implies 1\cdot3\cdot(1!)^2+2\cdot4\cdot(2!)^2+....+m\cdot(m+2)\cdot(m!)^2+\underbrace{(m+1)\{(m+1)+2\}\{(m+1)!\}^2}$

$\displaystyle=\{(m+1)!\}^2-1+\underbrace{(m+1)\{(m+1)+2\}\{(m+1)!\}^2} $

$\displaystyle=\{(m+1)!\}^2\{1+(m+1)(m+3)\}-1$

$\displaystyle=\{(m+1)!\}^2(m+2)^2-1$ as $1+(m+1)(m+3)=(m+2)^2$

$\displaystyle=\{(m+2)\cdot (m+1)!\}^2-1$

$\displaystyle=\{(m+2)!\}^2-1$

So, $f(k)$ will hold true for $k=m+1,$ if it holds true for $k=m$

Now establish the base  case i.e., $k=1$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$k(k+2)(k!)^2=\{(k+1)^2-1^2\}(k!)^2=\{(k+1)\cdot k!\}^2-(k!)^2=\{(k+1)!\}^2-(k!)^2$$

Can you recognize the [Telescoping Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?

Comment: I do now. =] I should've looked into that a little bit closer! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @user108626, added a link. Please set $k=1,2,3,$ etc. and see

Comment: So, it's obvious what is going on with this series. I'm still having a little trouble proving this. It is suggested to use induction but I get ((n+2)!)^2-((n+1)!)^2=((n+2)!)^2-1 which doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @user108626, not sure why you need induction when you have  a simpler option to derived the formula